# PHP breadcrumbs with list of paths

Tags: javascript, php, url, path, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumbs script that divides the URL with `/`and links each one to the same path. However, I am facing two issues:

1. I have an older website which didn't have `index.php` in many
   folders, so I need to add an array for which file to go to for that folder.
2. Some folders could have the same name in different locations..  so there could be a path like `example.com/something/Samename`, and another like `example.com/another/path/Samename`, and I need to set the title that shows in the breadcrumbs, so it's meaningful more than the path names.

So I want to add something like an array to tell it if the path is `/another/path/Samename` link to `thisfile.php`, and if it is the other folder link to another file.. etc., and if there is no array for that path then it links normally to the foldername, which means it has `index.php` file.

My current script is:

```
var path = "";
var href = document.location.href;
var s = href.split("/");
for (var i=2;i<(s.length-1);i++) {
path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf("/"+s[i])+s[i].length+1)+"/\">"+s[i]+"</A> / ";
}
i=s.length-1;
path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf(s[i])+s[i].length)+"\">"+s[i]+"</A>";
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + path;
document.writeln(url);
//-->
```

And this another script that does the same:

```
//this is a file named 'functions.php'
<?php
function breadcrumbs(){
  $bread = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  $url = '/';
  $returnString = "<span class='bc0'><a href='$url'>home</a>";
  for($i=1;$i<count($bread)-1;$i++){
    $url.=$bread[$i].'/';
    $returnString .= " |</span> <span class='bc$i'><a href='$url'>$bread[$i]</a>";
  }
  echo $returnString.'</span>';
}
?>

//in header of path
<?php include ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . 'functions.php'); ?>

//where the breadcrumbs show
<?php breadcrumbs(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you do this with a database? Maybe store the path in a column and the corresponding title in another column?

Comment: @Rasclatt , Thanks for the reply..  My server is not that strong, so I prefer to add it in an array or something in a php file and include it.

Comment: @Rasclatt , Seems no one knows how to do it without the database option..  Tell me how would that be possible so I test it...

Comment: Have you worked with a database before?

Comment: Ya, show me the schema and table/column names and I'll try.

Comment: Just do an auto increment id, case insensitive varchar with enough characters for a path, and the title you want for that path